# Execute pre-build event with project defaults pre-build event

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS C++ project and want to use a pre-build event, but don't want to overwrite the project's default pre-build event, which is part of the [project props file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#Anchor_7). Is there a way to execute both without copying the pre-build event from the props file.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `$(Command)` is replaced in the overriden entry with the command-line event from the props file.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by a parent project? You have to remember a build compiles all leaf projects first then makes its way up the dependency graph to the applications and test apps at the highest level.

If you don't want to change the prebuild step of what you call the parent you may consider changing the postbuild step.

Comment: You are right. It is either called the parent layer or project default, not parent project. I was referring to the upper layer, the project props file here. I corrected and clarified my question